# Intercept screen updates in android

Tags: android, screen, ondraw, intercept

is it possible to intercept screen updates in android?

I implemented a custom LinearLayout overrode the `onDraw()` method, but it will be only invoked when I do not click on child elements but somewhere else.

E.g. when i have a button in this view group and I click on this button, the `onDraw()` method won't be invoked on root level. On the other hand, if I touch a TextView the `onDraw()` will be invoked on root level. It seems like some elements consume the `onDraw()` method and do not pass it to the parent. Is there another method or event I can catch to get all the updates of the root view and its children on root level, except of extending each possible child and make custom implementations?

Edit: Maybe I have to clarify it a little bit. My purpose is to get bitmaps of the child views, every time they change. So e.g. if a button is a child view, I want to draw the view to a bitmap (get the drawing cache or invoking draw() manually to a custom canvas). The problem by using e.g. onClickListener is, that the the button state, while clicked, is actually "clicked", i need also an image of the button state which is set after and before it was clicked (http://developer.android.com/design/style/touch-feedback.html). Another problem is also, that I don't know which and how many child views are present, this should work for every possible created layout. So onClickListeners are also no option, except I would iterate through all children and check which type they are. But still there is the problem with the different states.

Answer (score 0):

dont create **onclick listeners** for child layouts of root layout.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create onClick listeners for child layouts and have your activity implement an onClickListener.  Override the onClick method for your activity and you can handle any clicks in there.

```
public class Acitivity implements OnClickListener
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
          //Handle clicks here
    }

}
```